# issues iterating over array with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to iterate a array using lodash but have issues with it.

Here is the code -

```js
const items = [{
  id: '1',
  name: 'A'
}, {
  id: '2',
  name: 'B'
}, {
  id: '3',
  name: 'C'
}, {
  id: '4',
  name: 'D'
}, {
  id: '5',
  name: 'E'
}]
var selectedItems = [0, 1]
selectedValues = _.forEach(selectedItems, function(val) {
  console.log('val -', val)
  console.log('items[val] -', items[val].name)
  return items[val].name
})
console.log('selectedValues - ', selectedValues)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

I expect the selectedValues should contain value - 'A', & 'B'

Comment: Why would you not just use native array methods to do this? You don't need an entire library to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

[`_.forEach`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#forEach) does not return any value to the assignment, simply use [`_.map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#map) if you wish to *return* a value;

```js
const items = [{
    id: '1',
    name: 'A'
  }, {
    id: '2',
    name: 'B'
  }, {
    id: '3',
    name: 'C'
  }, {
    id: '4',
    name: 'D'
  }, {
    id: '5',
    name: 'E'
  }]
var selectedItems = [0,1]
selectedValues = _.map(selectedItems, function(val){
      console.log('val -', val)
      console.log('items[val] -', items[val].name)
      return items[val].name      
    })
console.log('selectedValues - ', selectedValues)
// [
//   "A",
//   "B"
// ]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

---

With the use of an [anonymous function](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp) we can simplify the code quite some:

```
var selectedItems = [0,1]
selectedValues = _.map(selectedItems, (val) => items[val].name);
console.log('selectedValues - ', selectedValues)
```

```js
const items = [{id: '1', name: 'A'}, {id: '2', name: 'B'}, {id: '3', name: 'C'}, {id: '4', name: 'D'}, {id: '5', name: 'E'}]
var selectedItems = [0,1]
selectedValues = _.map(selectedItems, (val) => items[val].name);
console.log('selectedValues - ', selectedValues)
// [
//   "A",
//   "B"
// ]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to grab those objects that were selected by the user, you can get away with a pretty easy lodash setup by just using `filter` and `includes`.

*It's not clear if the `selectedItems` are indexes or Id's. Since Id's are a better use here (since that's what ID's are for), I'm assuming that in the code below*

```js
const items = [{
  id: '1',
  name: 'A'
}, {
  id: '2',
  name: 'B'
}, {
  id: '3',
  name: 'C'
}, {
  id: '4',
  name: 'D'
}, {
  id: '5',
  name: 'E'
}]
var selectedItems = [0, 1];
var selectedValues = _.filter(items, function(item) {
  return _.includes(selectedItems, +item.id);
});
console.log('selectedValues - ', selectedValues);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

But, you can do this without lodash pretty easily too:

```js
const items = [{
    id: '1',
    name: 'A'
  }, {
    id: '2',
    name: 'B'
  }, {
    id: '3',
    name: 'C'
  }, {
    id: '4',
    name: 'D'
  }, {
    id: '5',
    name: 'E'
  }];
const selectedItems = [0, 1];
const selectedValues = items.filter( i => selectedItems.includes(+i.id));
console.log('selectedValues - ', selectedValues);
```

- https://lodash.com/docs/#filter
- https://lodash.com/docs/#includes
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes